# Update table with random data

Tags: sql, ms-access, random, datatable, sql-update

This is an MS Access 2010 related question.

Is it possible to update the (empty) field of an existing table with data that have no connection with those already in the other fields of the table?

Assuming I have a field called "Letters" with 3 records (A, B and C). How can I update the field "Numbers" with 1, 2 and 3?
There is no connection at all between the values. I just want them to be in the same table. This should be done for large records and multiple fields.

Basically I am have to hold some reference date in the database and I would prefer to have them all in a single table.

The below retrieves the right numbers of records but they are all empty...

```
UPDATE tblDestination SET tblDestination.Numbers = [tblSource].[Numb];
```

Comment: in real life if you don't know where you put an item you won't find it unless you perform a search. same thing applies on a relational database. if you have data that is not identifiable by any relationship the data becomes meaningless. of course if you just want to dump some result into a table just copy and paste it. or perform insert with select command. or use excel.

Comment: @krish KM: If I use Insert with Select then I get a lot of blank fields (I mentioned there is no relationship between the data) and MS Excel is not acceptable for performance reasons.
How do you copy/paste in such case? How can I paste all values of a field into another table if there is no common field?