# Count records matching reference data set

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

This is an MS Access related question.

How can I count the number of records which bear for a defined field the same value as those of a defined field of another table?

I am trying the below but because I hold several times the same values in F1, the statement multiples the count() and I end up getting a far too large number.

```
SELECT Count([F1]) AS F1Count
FROM tblA, Y_tblReferenceData
WHERE ((([tblA].[F1])=[Y_tblReferenceData].[F1Ref]));
```

I do have duplicate records and I have to count them. DISTINCT is not an option.

The idea is to perform the equivalent of the below. Obviously I want to use SQL instead of looping through Recordset for performance reasons.

(28000+ records in the table, 6.7+ million iterations)

```
dblA = 0
rs.MoveFirst
rs2.MoveFirst

Do Until rs2.EOF
    If rs2.Fields(0) <> "" Then
        Do Until rs.EOF
            If rs.Fields(0).Value = rs2.Fields(0).Value Then
                dblA = dblA + 1
                rs.MoveFirst
                GoTo NextRecord
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
NextRecord:
    j = j + 1
    rs2.MoveNext
    rs.MoveFirst
Loop
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us a few sample rows from each of those 2 tables, and your desired outcome from those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very reason you are getting high numbers is because of the fact you are SELECTing FROM two tables, with no relationship. Try a JOIN

```
SELECT 
    Count([F1]) AS F1Count
FROM 
    tblA 
    INNER JOIN 
    Y_tblReferenceData
    ON 
    [tblA].[F1] = [Y_tblReferenceData].[F1Ref];
```

Comment: that's correct, 2 tables, no relationship. If I do what you suggest then I will corrupt the data since the data from the reference table will be added to the data set where I am counting. My data set has 28000 + records, If I don't use a JOIN I get 6 million. With INNER JOIN I get 1.3 million. Nobody knows how to do that?

Comment: Just to clarify JOINING in a Query will not **corrupt** data, it is only an extract. You are not updating anything. Next, why do you get 1.3 Million records when you JOIN? It should be 28000+, that is all. Probably it is because the fact you have table structure wrong somewhere. Would you mind adding some sample data in your original post?

Comment: if one is adding reference data to a data set to be analyzed obviously the data set is messed up. I call that corrupted but you are welcome to suggest a more relevant term. As a matter of fact the record table structure is not ideal here. A structure similar to an excel sheet where relationships can be broken would be more appropriate here. In an earlier post I have asked if the table structure can be de-constructed. Nobody has answered yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371089/update-table-with-random-data

Comment: You are confusing different things. Please show some data, please be aware there are two tables, each having data of its own. Table A has a field that is a reference field to the field in Table B. That is all. No where no corruption, not messing up.

Comment: I would love to show the data set... but stackoverflow does not enable that (and many debates on the topic still have not triggered any changes). I appreciate you are trying to help; unfortunately this time we won't succeed. If I was building in T-SQL I would use variables... but with Access I cannot do that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*) AS F1Count FROM
(    
    SELECT DISTINCT [F1] AS F1Count
    FROM tblA, Y_tblReferenceData
    WHERE [tblA].[F1]=[Y_tblReferenceData].[F1Ref]
) AS inner
```

Comment: @Mike Nakis: this is not helping, I do have duplicate records and I must count them. DISTINCT would corrupt the count()